# Loading an image using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Unable to load an image in PyCharm

I am just starting out using PyCharm and I can get image to load in IDLE.

Here is the result in Pycharm Python console:

Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("C:\Users\Kelly\Desktop\CSCI 131 Python\ch_07\smokey.jpg")

```
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

> NOTE: I got the same syntax error in IDLE until I moved the `.jpg` file
>   to the Python 3.7 folder. Nothing I have tried in PyCharm has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Kelly\Desktop\CSCI 131 Python\ch_07\smokey.jpg")
```

The Reason for your error was that your image path contained backslash `\` in it. As we know backslashes `\` are treated as escape characters by the compiler, and therefore interprets any character following a `\` as a escape sequence, which is not our intention here. So, In order to get through this problem provide raw path of your image file, by using `r` before the image path string.